# Setting default values in a python subclass, OOP?

Tags: python, oop

solution is

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, mileage):
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.mileage = mileage

    def seating_capacity(self, capacity):
        return f"The seating capacity of a {self.name} is {capacity} passengers"

class Bus(Vehicle):
    # assign default value to capacity
    def seating_capacity(self, capacity=50):
        return super().seating_capacity(capacity=50)

School_bus = Bus("School Volvo", 180, 12)
print(School_bus.seating_capacity())
```

I don't understand: `def seating_capacity(self, capacity=50): ...`

Why do they reproduce the method in the subclass and then return it with super?

```
def seating_capacity(self, capacity=50):
        return super().seating_capacity(capacity=50)
```

Comment: It looks like a failed attempt at allowing `Bus` to reuse that method, but whilst adding a default value for the `capacity` parameter.

Comment: Looks like they wanted a way for Bus vehicles to have a default capacity of 50 passengers, without needing to provide the actual capacity as an argument.

Comment: But I think the actual call should be `return super().seating_capacity(capacity)`, because the parent `seating_capacity()` function does not take keyword arguments.

Comment: It does it takes the argument capacity

Comment: @John *"does not take keyword arguments"* - Eh? Yes it does.

Comment: What I'm wondering is, why is `capacity` not an attribute? If you're learning Python, wherever you got this from might not be a good source, TBH.

Comment: Are you aware that `super()` accesses methods/attributes on the parent class? I'm trying to narrow down what you're asking exactly so I can point you to existing answers or other resources.

Comment: @wjandrea What?  The definition of `Vehicle.seating_capacity()` does not mention keyword arguments...

Comment: @John By default, arguments can be passed as positional or keyword (i.e. `.seating_capacity(capacity)` or `.seating_capacity(capacity=capacity)`). To make them positional-only, you'd use a slash: `def seating_capacity(self, capacity, /):`

Comment: @wjandrea Huh.  I knew positional args could be passed as keyword, but not the other way round.  TIL.

Comment: @John Are you maybe confusing keyword arguments with parameters that have a default value? (`=` in a call vs `=` in a def, respectively)

Comment: @wjandrea Apparently, yes I am confusing those things.

Answer (score 0):

This code is using  method overriding in Python. The `Bus` class overrides the `seating_capacity` method inherited from `Vehicle`. So if user do not send any parameter for `capacity`, the default value will be used.

Comment: That's not really the whole story, because if the user does pass in a `capacity`, it's unused.

Comment: BTW, the usual terminology is that `capacity` itself is the parameter, and the user would pass in an **argument**.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in the code you posted was in the super call. It uses `capacity=50` which just means that the call always uses `50` and not the value passed in.

This is the corrected code:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, mileage):
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.mileage = mileage

    def seating_capacity(self, capacity):
        return f"The seating capacity of a {self.name} is {capacity} passengers"

class Bus(Vehicle):
    # assign default value to capacity
    def seating_capacity(self, capacity=50):
        return super().seating_capacity(capacity)

School_bus = Bus("School Volvo", 180, 12)
print(School_bus.seating_capacity(42))
print(School_bus.seating_capacity())
```

The output is:

```
The seating capacity of a School Volvo is 42 passengers
The seating capacity of a School Volvo is 50 passengers
```

other wise both lines would show `50 passengers`